# Правильно ли будет использовать только для некоторых страниц react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Правильно ли будет использовать только для некоторых страниц react? 
и делать на каждой странице отдельный app.js который будет вставлять компоненты определенной страницы это правильно или лучше просто js юзать? сайт на ларавел сделан

Comment: Так делать можно. Но это будет не SPA. Если есть такая задача - то делайте.

Comment: смотря что вам нужно